# Let $G$ be a group and $g \in G$. Assume that $g$ is conjugate to $g^2$. Prove that $g^{-1}$ is conjugate to $g^{-4}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a group and $g \in G$. Assume that $g$ is conjugate to $g^2$. Prove that $g^{-1}$ is conjugate to $g^{-4}$.

My attempt is to use the definition and manipulate the given equation.
Given that $g$ is conjugate to $g^2$, there exists an $x \in G$ such that: $g=xg^{2}x^{-1}$.
I take the inverse:
$g^{-1}=(xg^{2}x^{-1})^{-1}=xg^{-2}x^{-1}$.
Dividing on both sides by g (on the right), I get:
$g^{-2}=xg^{-2}x^{-1}g^{-1}$ 
and using previous equation:
$g^{-2}=xg^{-2}x^{-1}(xg^{-2}x^{-1})=xg^{-4}x^{-1}$,
Substituting this into the second equation:
$g^{-1}=xg^{-2}x^{-1}=x(xg^{-4}x^{-1})x^{-1}=x^2g^{-4}x^{-2}$
so $g^{-1}$ is conjugate to $g^{-4}$.
Is this solution correct?

Comment: You need to write down $g^{-1}=yg^{-4}y^{-1}$ with an explicit $y$. So far you only wrote that for $g^{-2}$. And your formula $(xg^{2}x^{-1})^{-1}=x^{-1}g^{-2}x$ is wrong, because $(ab)^{-1}\neq a^{-1}b^{-1}$. So, no, it is not correct.

Comment: You're right, I edited the post, how about now?

Comment: It's easier to start with $g^2=xgx^{-1}$ and find $y$ such that $g^{-4}=yg^{-1}y^{-1}.$ In particular, you can use $y=x^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some $h$ with $g=hg^2h^{-1}.$ Then

$$\begin{align}
hg^{-2}h^{-1}&=(h^{-1})^{-1}(g^2)^{-1}h^{-1}\\
&=(hg^2h^{-1})^{-1}\\
&=g^{-1}.
\end{align}$$

Now:

$$\begin{align}
h^2g^{-4}h^{-2}&=h(hg^{-4}h^{-1})h^{-1}\\
&=h(\color{purple}{hg^{-2}}(\color{purple}{h^{-1}}\color{orange}{h})\color{orange}{g^{-2}h^{-1}})h^{-1}\\
&=hg^{-2}h^{-1}\\
&=g^{-1}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Check to make sure that and why each step of the following is correct. $$xgx^{-1} = g^2 \implies (xgx^{-1})^2 = g^4$$ $$\implies xg^2x^{-1} = g^4$$
$$\implies x(xgx^{-1})x^{-1} = g^4.$$ In particular, $x^2gx^{-2} = g^4$.